# OctoberCMS (Laravel) Caching "permission issues" on Azure windows hosting

Tags: laravel, caching, filesystems, octobercms

OctoberCMS (Laravel) app. Installed an operational on Azure WebApp hosting. It is PAAS hosting. Periodically log file reports:

Again the server is an Azure WebApp, windows system running IIS. Files do get cached, but periodically the logs report permission issues when caching files. This only occurs when OCtoberCMS attempts to cache a page. All other caching seems to run with no issue.

```php
production.ERROR: ErrorException: file_put_contents(D:\home\site\wwwroot\storage\framework/cache-test/e0/02/e002af343c78d6258ed4f1ddedcbe35f2ffe464e): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:122
```